# jQuery knockout dynamic array of radiobuttons, values must be boolean

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, radio-button

Totally stuck on this. Read around but unbelievably can't find anyone else with potentially more than two radiobuttons requiring their values as boolean.

Given a view that looks like this:-
[image]

corresponding knockout viewmodel:-

```
function driver(name, license, maindriver) {
var self = this;

self.DriverName = ko.observable(name);
self.License = ko.observable(license);
self.IsMainDriver = ko.observable(maindriver);

}
```

I'm having all sorts of trouble getting these to post with an actual boolean value for 'IsMainDriver'. Which ever one of these is selected must be set to true. The others must be set to false. I've tried various tweaks to the html below, but I'm not getting anywhere. Some posts say something about the true/false being set as strings e.g. "true" or "false". I've tried knockout observable extenders, callbacks but as I said nothing has worked so far. Sometimes I get an 'on' is not valid for 'IsMainDriver' in firebug. The best effort I've had so far is using a custom binding where the only problem was the 'IsMainDriver' observable was never set to false again once it had been set to true, so basically despite only one being 'checked'in the view, on posting, multiple rows had 'IsMainDriver' set to true (hope that makes sense). Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
<td>
  <input name="mainDriverGroup[]" type="radio" data-bind="checked: IsMainDriver, value:IsMainDriver()" class="required" data-val-required="Please choose the main driver." />
  <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="mainDriverGroup[]" data-val-replace="true"></span>
 </td>
```

Comment: Add http://jsfiddle.net/ with the problem

Comment: Good idea, sorry forgot about jsfiddle. Here is an example I think pretty much shows the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/renz/gc6zV/  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've created the very base [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XHeeT/6/) with the problem.

Since you have only one radio button I created computed observable that transform Boolean value to the appropriate value for knockout and back.

```
    this.IsMainDriverFormatted = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        if (self.IsMainDriver() === true) {
            return 'on';
        }
        else {
            return 'off';
        }
    },
    write: function (value) {
        if (value === 'on') {
            self.IsMainDriver(true);
        }
        else {
            self.IsMainDriver(false);
        }
    },
    owner: this
    });
```

In a View 'checked' binding was used.

```
<input name="IsMainDriver" type="radio" data-bind="checked: IsMainDriverFormatted" />
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this, I'm new to jsfiddle but everytime I run this I just get "Sam Fernandes", checking one of the other drivers doesn't seem to work for me. I took your computed function though and modified my fiddle above http://jsfiddle.net/renz/gc6zV/4/ still isn't working though :(

Comment: You need to bing computed observable IsMainDriverFormatted instead of IsMainDriver:  <input name="IsMainDriver" type="radio" data-bind="checked: IsMainDriverFormatted" />. Also as I understood from your post you want to have only one selected driver. Am I right?

Comment: Thats nearly correct, Lets say there are three drivers, only one of these can be the main driver. So when this is posted back to my controller I would have something like "driver1 IsMainDriver=true", "driver2 IsMainDriver=false", "driver3 IsMainDriver=false" etc... Updated my checked binding http://jsfiddle.net/renz/gc6zV/6/ sorry If I didn't explain myself properly the first time. Thanks.

Comment: To achieve this you may use this logic

//Subscribe to changes of the observable IsMainDriver. 
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.drivers(), function (item) {
        item.IsMainDriver.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            if (newValue === true) {
                // Loop through the array.
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.drivers(), function (driver) {
                    if (driver.DriverName() !== item.DriverName()) {

                        driver.IsMainDriver(false);
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    });
For more details look on my fiddle.